# Receive multiple message types in one BizTalk HTTP receive location

Tags: http, biztalk

Is it possible to have a BizTalk HTTP receive location (using BtsHttpReceive.dll) and receive multiple inbound message types?

For example I have:

- Schema1, with field OrderID and CustomerName
- Schema2, with field OrderNr and CustomerFullName
- MainSchema, with field OrderRef and Name
- Mapping from Schema1 > MainSchema
- Mapping from Schema2 > MainSchema

I have a website using BTSHttpReceive, and if a client submits a post request to that website with OrderID and CustomerName in the POST data, then message Schema1 should be created.

If the client submites a post request with OrderNr and CustomerFullName then message Schema2 should be created.
And in the receive port, i will have the Inbound mappings:

- Schema1 > MainSchema
- Schema2 > MainSchema

I tried running the application like this using XMLReceivePipeline but I got an error

> There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: "Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLReceive, ..
>   Reason: No Disassemble stage components can recognize the data.

Is this scenario possible to achieve in BizTalk?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that scenario is possible, however

1. All the schemas need to be XML ones (you can't do it with a flat file schema).
2. All the schemas need to be deployed to BizTalk.
3. All the schemas need to have a unique namespace and the XML received needs to have one of those namespaces.

Comment: Yes, I did all three. But the things is, when i execute the POST request, the message body is taken from the POST body. And it seems that BizTalk can't transform this automatically to the XML message, or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you looked at the suspended message to see what BizTalk has received? The post body should be XML as per in 1. above so what transformation are you expecting?